# UITransitionView on top of ViewController using UIModalPresentationStyle.OverCurrentContext

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I'm trying to set a view controller on top of another while keeping some of the first on visible.

However, I can't see the first one because I have a UITransitionView with a UIView on top of it (the first one is in the hierarchy and that's how I know *.OverCurrentContext* is working)

This should be a very simple code and I'm not sure what's going on. I know I can't touch the UITransitionView and that's why I'm not sure what to do.

```
let vc = storyBoard.instantiateInitialViewController() as MyPresenterViewController
vc.view.backgroundColor = .clearColor()
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .OverCurrentContext

viewControllerToPresentIn.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Best regards,

Comment: You need to explain what you're doing with the UITransitionView. How is it getting added?

Comment: @rdelmar I'm not doing anything, that's why I'm not sure why it's coming up. It shouldn't have come with a simple presentVC right?

Comment: I don't know why this would be happening. When I do it (replacing viewControllerToPresentIn with self), it works fine. What is viewControllerToPresentIn?

Comment: It's self, I just wrote it that way to make it easier to understand

Comment: Is storyBoard a different storyboard from the one self is in?

Comment: It's the very same one @rdelmar

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense then. You shouldn't be instantiating the initial view controller in the storyboard that you're already in -- that controller has already been instantiated (when the app started up), and what you're doing with the posted code is creating another instance of that initial controller. You should edit your question to describe what controllers you have, and what flow you want between them.

Comment: You can achieve this simply by using container view to add another view controller in a view controller and animate the transition.

Comment: @rdelmar UITransitionViews are automatically added.  it's a total PITA.  check out the heirarchy inspector in xcode.  the only solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53922625/294884

Answer (score 2):

A little late to the party with this response, but I recently had at a similar problem. A modal I wanted to present (with a semi-transparent veil) was being contained by a white UITransitionView, hiding the underlying views. I suspect this TransitionView gets injected when you issue a `controller.present()` call to show your Modal in some circumstances (but don't know why or when)

As a quick and dirty workaround, you can try to clear the background of the parent views of your modal before you present. For some reason, the UITransitionView then also gets a clear colour once you present your modal.

```
extension UIView {
   //This will eventually get to the UITransitionView and clear the background.
   func clearHierarchyBackground() {
    self.backgroundColor = .clear
    if let superView = self.superview {
        superview.clearHierarchyBackground()
    }
  }
}

let parentController = MyParentViewController()
let childController = MyModalViewController()
childController.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen //.overCurrentContext should also work..
childController.view.clearHierarchyBackground() 
/* The above makes your controller root view .clear
so you need to add subviews with transparency & 
content as you see fit.*/
parentController.present(childController, animated:true....)
```

Comment: Damn, doesn't work for me!

Comment: ah, the only correct and full solution is: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53922625/294884