# Pass touches through a UIViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, touch

I have a view controller that I overlay on top of another view controller. I just need the top view controller so I can overlay a temporary pop up notification, and having an overlayed VC allows me to present this over a UITableViewController as you can't add subviews to tableview controllers directly.

Is it possible to interact with the bottom view controller while it has another view controller covering it. If this were a view or a window you would achieve this by setting user interaction to false or using hitTest but neither of these approaches works for a view controller.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "covering"? What is the relationship between these view controllers?

Comment: VC1 calls presentViewController(VC2). VC2 has         modalPresentationStyle = .OverCurrentContext, backgroundColour.clear. I want touches to register on VC1 not VC2.

Comment: is vc2.view a subview of vc1.view?

Comment: No. It's not a subview.

Comment: Did you ever solve your problem?

Comment: No. I don't think I did.

Comment: @MarkBridges the Tiran answer below is perfect, maybe needs a tick if you're still around!

Answer (score 20):

Create subclass like this

```
class TouchDelegatingView: UIView {
    weak var touchDelegate: UIView? = nil


    override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        guard let view = super.hitTest(point, with: event) else {
            return nil
        }

        guard view === self, let point = touchDelegate?.convert(point, from: self) else {
            return view
        }

        return touchDelegate?.hitTest(point, with: event)
    }
}
```

Then in your ViewController set view class (you can do it directly in xib, or inside loadView() method)

And add

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let delegatingView = view as? TouchDelegatingView {
            delegatingView.touchDelegate = presentingViewController?.view
        }
    }
}
```

Also you can use this mechanism to delegate touches to any other view, no matter if it

Comment: No matter if it is what?

Comment: oops =) Sorry, I don't remember =) You can just ignore that