# iOS - After presentViewController nothing clickable except navigationBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, navigation

I try to present viewController(`BrandViewController`) from view(`MainCollectionViewCell.m`) by using `didselectItemAt` method. So,

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        UIViewController *currentTopVC = [self currentTopViewController];
        BrandViewController *brandVC = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"BrandVC"];

        [currentTopVC presentViewController:brandVC animated:true completion:nil];
}

- (UIViewController *)currentTopViewController {
    UIViewController *topVC = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController];
    while (topVC.presentedViewController) {
        topVC = topVC.presentedViewController;
    }
    return topVC;
}
```

This code shows `BrandViewController` correctly, but I cannot click any buttons or images from `BrandViewController`except my back button. Can you give me any ideas about this problem?

---

edited : I have two collectionViews. One is in MainViewController(`MainCollectionView`), and the other is inside of `MainCollectionViewCell`(`didSelectItemAt` method called from here).

edited2: presented View hierarchy has two `UITransitionView`

[image]

Comment: make sure your brandVC.view.userInteractionEnable = true.

Comment: @jigneshVadadoriya Thank you, I tried but still not working..

Comment: why you have to find top view controller? cant you just use `self`?

Comment: @Tj3n I try to call that method from `view` not from `controller`. So, I cannot catch `controller` by `self`(self is my collectionViewCell).

Comment: got it, try print out the `currentTopVC ` you got, if its not your `MainCollectionView ` class, then its the problem, else try replace your `BrandViewController ` with a blank controller with a button, and see if you can interact

Comment: I got `currentTopVC : <UINavigationController: 0x7ff9a6835800>` from printing `currentTopVC`. Is it a problem?

Comment: inspect view hierarchy : http://stackoverflow.com/a/24732640/3901620

Comment: @KKRocks I have two `UITransitionView` from presented view, but I can see just one `UITransitionView` from other views.

Comment: i think it is check: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39967835/3901620

Comment: problem looking here...         UIViewController *currentTopVC = [self currentTopViewController];

Comment: please check r u getting right controller here

Comment: @KKRocks If I set my `brandVC.view.userInterationEnabled = false` entire view not working.

Comment: @ajjjjjjjj printing `currentTopVC` result is `<UINavigationController: 0x7ff9a6835800>`. Did I get wrong ViewController?

Comment: yes, now try to push on navigation bar instead of presenting, it will work, Still if you want to present , then i will help you

Comment: i gave Answer first man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try code below:

```
UINavigationController *currentTopVC = (UINavigationController *)[self currentTopViewController];
BrandViewController *brandVC = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"BrandVC"];
[currentTopVC pushViewController:brandVC animated:YES];
```

Comment: You are my Life saver, Time saver!!

Comment: @ajjjjjjjj oh, thank you for you also. Can you explain what the problem is? Then I can vote for you also!

Comment: You can only present Viewcontroller on on Any viewcontroller And you were presenting on Navigation stack